# How to calculate SMMA (Smoothed moving average) with Polars?

Tags: python, recursion, moving-average, python-polars

I would like to calculate SMMA with Polars.
If possible through one select since I want to get Expression instead of DataFrame.

I have `frame_length (window_size)` and price `DataFrame(['1.2, 5.4, 6.1, 4.3, ...])`.

In plain Python it is quite straight forward:

```
def get_smma(sum_in_frame: float, prev_smma: float, frame_length: int) -> float:
    return (sum_in_frame - prev_smma) / float(frame_length)
```

Or at least is it possible to have `rolling recursion` or access `previous calculated value` in Polars?

Solution I came up in the end:
using formula:

```
N - moving frame length
SMMA(0) = SUM(PRICE[0:N-1]) / N # First SMMA = Simple Moving Avg
SMMA(i) = (SMMA(i-1) * (N-1) + PRICE[i]) / N
```

```
    def get_smma_df(
            frame_len: int,
            price_candle_df: DataFrame,
            src_field='close_price'
    ) -> DataFrame:

        def get_smma_value(acc_series, row_series):
            price = row_series[0]
            rol_sum = row_series[1]
            prev_smma = acc_series[0]

            if rol_sum is None:
                return prev_smma

            if prev_smma is None:
                smma = rol_sum / frame_len
            else:
                smma = (prev_smma * (frame_len - 1) + price) / frame_len
            return smma

        df = (
            price_candle_df
            .select(
                price=pl.col(src_field),
                rol_sum=pl.col(src_field).rolling_sum(frame_len)
            )
            .transpose()
            .select(
                smma=pl.cumfold(
                    acc=None,
                    exprs=pl.all(),
                    function=get_smma_value
                )
            )
            .unnest('smma')
            .transpose(column_names=["smma"])
        )

        return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to access previous values is via [`pl.cumfold`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.cumfold.html) - which is a horizontal operation.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"price": [1.2, 5.4, 6.1, 4.3]})

df.select("price").unstack(1).select(smma = 
   pl.cumfold(
      acc = 0, 
      exprs = pl.all(),
      function = lambda prev_smma, price: 
         (df.get_column("price").sum() - prev_smma) / df.height
   )
)
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│ smma                            │
│ ---                             │
│ struct[4]                       │
╞═════════════════════════════════╡
│ {4.25,3.1875,3.453125,3.386719} │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: But how convert smma df with struct inside to simple series Dataframe?

Comment: Well, you could add `.unnest("smma").select(price = pl.concat_list(pl.all()).flatten())` - but I believe the recommendation is to just use a python loop for this type of task. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7658